# Helm Install fails with Error: could not find tiller from within Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: bash, powershell, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, azure-cloud-shell

Helm install called from the cloud shell worked last week but now regardless of using bash or powershell it returns

> Error: could not find tiller

Last week I was able to create an ingress controller by following the Microsoft article  [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)

now when I get to the helm install step I get the error indicated in the title.  To recreate this issue:

- Do *clouddrive unmount* from within the powershell cloud shell.
- Using the Azure portal delete your cloudshell file share in Azure Storage.
- create a 2 node 'B2s' Kubernetes Service using Advanced networking using the provided defaults.
- Open the Cloud Shell using either bash or Powershell.
- Do *az aks get-credentials* and provide the name of your AKS cluster.
- Do *kubectl create namespace ingress-basic*
- Do *helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/*
- the command above will warn that you need to perform a helm init.
- Do *a az aks list* to get the servicePrincipalProfile:clientId of your AKS cluster
- Do *helm init --service-account* using the clientId of the command above for the service-account parameter
- Do the helm install using the parameters from the Microsoft Docs [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls)

At this point you should get the error mentioned in the title.
Any suggestions on what I might be missing.

Comment: Tiller is gone and no longer a thing as of helm 3.x. What version of helm are you trying to use?

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that I tried to install helm multiple times.  Every time it indicates that it already exists on the cluster.  But every helm install gives me the same error.

Comment: i think cloud shell is still using helm v2, not v3, hence the need for tiller

Answer (score 0):

right, I think you need to actually create a service account in kubernetes in order for this to work, sample code:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

helm init --service-account tiller

# Users in China: You will need to specify a specific tiller-image in order to initialize tiller. 
# The list of tiller image tags are available here: https://dev.aliyun.com/detail.html?spm=5176.1972343.2.18.ErFNgC&repoId=62085. 
# When initializing tiller, you'll need to pass in --tiller-image

helm init --service-account tiller \
--tiller-image registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/tiller:<tag>
```

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/options/helm2/helm-init/

whereas you are trying to use Azure Service Principal instead of Kubernetes Service Account. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Nope same error.  I did every command you indicated and I still get Error: could not find tiller.  Also I did not have to do a helm init last week.  Microsoft indicates that tiller is already installed in the cluster.

Comment: As a further bit of information I tried to upgrade Helm to V3 and because you cannot be root within Azure Cloud Shell the installation fails with permission denied

Comment: well, in this case maybe your cluster isnt actually working

Comment: I can deploy yaml files to the cluster.  What I can no longer do is run anything in helm that requires tiller.  Helm informs me that tiller is installed if I do an upgrade or attempt to reinstall tiller.  But doing any command that requires tiller fails.

Comment: doesn't mean it's working. what is the node status? what is the pod status? what is going on with the tiller pod?

Answer (score 0):

OK two items.

1. Tiller was not installed.  on 2/14/2020 I was able to install an ingress controller using helm.  But on 2/18 I was not able to do a helm install --dry-run on a chart because of the above mentioned error.  Anyway after following this documentation [Install applications with Helm in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm) I got Tiller installed properly.
2. After getting Tiller properly installed the helm install command for the ingress controller [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls) was failing with chart not found error.

I modified the command from

```
helm install nginx stable/nginx-ingress \
```

to

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
```

and the chart is now deploying properly.
I am now back to where I was on 2/14.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

OK got the following letter from Microsoft Tech Support letting me know that there was a problem with Azure Cloud Shell. I did a Helm version this morning and now see

> version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.1",
>   GitCommit:"afe70585407b420d0097d07b21c47dc511525ac8",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}

Which I did not see on 2/14.  So I looks like I was NOT crazy and that Microsoft has fixed this issue. Based on her letter the issue with the chart name should also be resolved.

> Hi Brian, Thanks for your update. We are so sorry for the
>   inconvenience. There was an error in the script which builds the cloud
>   shell image. Helm released 2.16.3 more recently than 3.1 and the build
>   script picked that up as the 'latest' release, causing the inadvertent
>   downgrade. As helm v3 does not require tiller pod, so the tiller pod
>   cannot be found when using helm v2. The helm version will be
>   re-upgraded in the next release. As confirmed by you, the queries
>   related to this issue have been solved and hence I will go ahead and
>   archive your case at this time. Please remember that support for this
>   case does not end here. Should you need further assistance with your
>   issue, you can reach out to me and I will continue working with you.
>                   Here is a summary of the key points of the case for your records.
>                   Issue Definition: Helm install Error: could not find tiller.
>                   Resolution/Suggestion Summary: You could refer to the follow the below document to configure helm V2:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm#install-an-application-with-helm-v2.
>   Alternatively, you may also use the command below to upgrade the helm
>   to version 3 as a workaround: curl https://aka.ms/cloud-shell-helm3 |
>   bash. The command ‘helm version’ can be used to verify the version of
>   Helm you have installed.
>
> Besides, the syntax for helm 3 is different from helm 2. The syntax
>   for helm v3 is ‘helm install [NAME] [CHART] [flags]’  while for hem v2
>   is ‘helm install [CHART] [flags]’. So you need to remove the word
>   nginx after the word install if you are using helm v2. You could refer
>   to the following document for more information:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-helm#install-an-application-with-helm-v2
>
> It was my pleasure to work with you on this service request. Please do
>   not hesitate to contact me if I can be of further assistance.   Thank
>   you very much for your support of Microsoft Azure. Have a nice day!